# Is there a way to declare a tuple without using the array literal type notation?

Tags: typescript

Ok, so this is mostly for my curiosity. See below code:

```
const a: [string, number] = ["string", 1]; //valid
const b: Array<string, number> = ["string", 1]; //invalid
const c: Array<[string, number]> = ["string", 1] //invalid, it means [["string", 1]]
```

There seems to be no way to declare a tuple unless you use `[]` notation. My next thought was to look for a tuple type, but there seems to be nothing built in.

You could declare a `Tuple` type like so: `type Tuple<K, V> = [K, V]` but that defeats the whole idea.

Also something like :

```
let d: Array<string | number> = ["string", 1]
```

Would compile but you would be able to assign something like `["string", "another string", 1, 2, "stuff"]` to it.

**Update 1:**
As indicated by @jcalz `type Tuple<K, V> = [K, V]` is incorrect in that it limits the number of elements of the tuple type to 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What exactly "defeats the whole idea" of `type Tuple<K, V>`?  Is it that `Tuple<>` doesn't allow an arbitrary number of type parameters?  Or that it uses `[]` inside its definition?

---

Here is one possible path to a solution, depending on your use case:

```
type Tuple<A, B = never, C = never, D = never, E = never, F = never, G = never> =
  [G] extends [never] ? [F] extends [never] ? [E] extends [never] ?
  [D] extends [never] ? [C] extends [never] ? [B] extends [never] ?
  [A] : [A, B] : [A, B, C] : [A, B, C, D] : [A, B, C, D, E] :
  [A, B, C, D, E, F] : [A, B, C, D, E, F, G]
```

Here, `Tuple<>` is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) which uses [default generic parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to allow you to specify anywhere between one and seven tuple elements:

```
const e: Tuple<string, number> = ["string", 1]; // okay
```

If you need more elements you can extend the above definition, although you can never get an arbitrary number of them without something like [variadic kinds](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453), which are not part of TypeScript (as of 2.9 anyway).

Or maybe this doesn't count because tuple syntax is being used inside the definition.  If you want to completely avoid tuple syntax, you could try to make a type which is similar to a tuple... something like this for the two-element case:

```
interface FakeTuple2<A, B> extends Array<A | B> {
  readonly length: 2,
  0: A,
  1: B,
}
```

This is tuple-like enough for many purposes, depending on what you need:

```
const f: FakeTuple2<string, number> = ["string", 1]; // okay
```

And if you want a variable number of elements as well as the fake tuple, you could use both approaches above to get something like:

```
type StripNever<T> = Pick<T, { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends never ? never : K }[keyof T]>
type FakeTuple<A, B = never, C = never, D = never, E = never, F = never, G = never> =
  Array<A | B | C | D | E | F | G> & 
  StripNever<{ 0: A, 1: B, 2: C, 3: D, 4: E, 5: F, 6: G }> & {
    length: [G] extends [never] ? [F] extends [never] ? [E] extends [never] ?
    [D] extends [never] ? [C] extends [never] ? [B] extends [never] ? 
    1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : 5 : 6 : 7
  }
```

which also works for one through seven elements and can be extended.

---

So those are some ideas for you.  Hope they help.  Good luck!

Comment: Great answer as always. @marthinus-engelbrecht I am curious why one would avoid the tuple type syntax though

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir It's a long story and might warrant another question. I'm in the process of writing a babel-like language plugin that extends collections using the typescript compiler API and there are certain cases where I need to replace all references to array literals with my extended array class. So I ran into the tuple situation when initializing a Map with an array literal which is really a "tuple literal" in that context in I'm not sure of the best approach to deal with it.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the detailed answer. I didn't actually think about the fact that `Tuple<K, V> = [K,V]` is incorrect in that it limits the total amount of items. So I meant it 'defeats the idea' in the sense that I'm using the array literal syntax. Will update my question.